# How to get records that don't exist based on 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following table setups:

//clients

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Id        | Client   | Status     |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1         | A        | Active     |
| 2         | B        | Active     |
| 3         | C        | Inactive   |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

//manager Table

```
+-----------+----------+
| clientId  | managerId|
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | 1        |
| 2         | 2        |
| 3         | 3        |
+-----------+----------+
```

//users table

```
+-----------+----------+
| id        | firstName|
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | Carrera  |
| 2         | Taylor   |
| 3         | Diaz     |
+-----------+----------+
```

//Desired Output

```
+-----------+----------+
| clientId  | managerId|
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | 2        |
| 1         | 3        |
| 2         | 1        |
| 2         | 3        |
+-----------+----------+
```

How can I write a query to get the desired output? I have tried something like this but the output is not desired:

```
select c.id as "Client"
     , u.id as "user" 
  from managers cm 
  left 
  join users u 
    on u.id = cm.managerId 
  left 
  join clients c 
    on c.id = cm.clientId 
 where cm.managerId not in (select id from users where firstName like '%a%') 
   and cm.clientId not in (select id from clients where status = 'Active');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th interesting think is the `WHERE`clause, as you need the active client and exclude  the existing connection in the table managers

> ```
> CREATE TABLE managers (
>   `clientId` INTEGER,
>   `managerId` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO managers
>   (`clientId`, `managerId`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1'),
>   ('2', '2'),
>   ('3', '3');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Clients (
>   `Id` INTEGER,
>   `Client` VARCHAR(1),
>   `Status` VARCHAR(8)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Clients
>   (`Id`, `Client`, `Status`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'A', 'Active'),
>   ('2', 'B', 'Active'),
>   ('3', 'C', 'Inactive');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `firstName` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO users
>   (`id`, `firstName`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Carrera'),
>   ('2', 'Taylor'),
>   ('3', 'Diaz');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT c.`Id` as ClientId ,u.id as ManagerId  FROM users u CROSS JOIN Clients c
> WHERE c.`Status` = 'Active' AND (u.id,c.`Id`) NOT IN (SELECT `clientId`, `managerId` FROM managers)
> ORDER By ClientId,ManagerId
> ```
>
> ```
> ClientId | ManagerId
> -------: | --------:
>        1 |         2
>        1 |         3
>        2 |         1
>        2 |         3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a2a0b1b7598c36a29e0197e935abbe67)*